# AngularJS - How to get the corresponding DOM section of a scope?

Tags: angularjs

For example, if I access a sibling scope with `scope.$$nextSibling` - how do I retrieve its corresponding HTML section, or perform modifications like adding a class or so on?

Comment: Why do you want to get the dom element? Normally dom manipulations are done in a directive.

Comment: And I am writing a directive...

Comment: do you have a plunk/fiddle of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Very much WIP - http://plnkr.co/edit/az1HDuR9f7JZ6ksYX63c?p=preview

Comment: so you want to press a key and find the child element that maps to that key?

Answer (score 0):

In a controller you can get the element that the controller has been applied to:

```
.controller('MyController', function($element){});
```

I wouldn't do this myself, as the controller should not be doing dom manipulation.
I have not found a way to get the element for an arbitrary scope, but also can't see why this would be useful.